Multiple instances of the same thread
I would like to run the same thread (e.g. accel()) multiple times. I am controlling multiple sections, each of which needs to accelerate independently. I have a code which looks like this:
while True:
    if get_sensor():
        accel(sect)

I am getting an error message like this:
Accelerating sector 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/runner/Gondola-Control-v101/main.py", line 1, in <module>
import drivecontrol as drv
File "/home/runner/Gondola-Control-v101/drivecontrol.py", line 1, in <module>
import communication as comms
File "/home/runner/Gondola-Control-v101/communication.py", line 2, in <module>
import rlink as rdo
File "/home/runner/Gondola-Control-v101/rlink.py", line 3, in <module>
import motorcontrol as mtr
File "/home/runner/Gondola-Control-v101/motorcontrol.py", line 38, in <module>
init()
File "/home/runner/Gondola-Control-v101/motorcontrol.py", line 28, in init
accelsector.start()
File "/nix/store/1gc9wvzsy15pclrqfspii166p52lmh5i-python3-3.10.13/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 930, in start
raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once


Why not just make a new thread? (Although this sounds like it may not be a job for threads at all.)

Could you just keep the thread running, and send it more work to do?

Re, "I would like to run the same thread (e.g. accel()) multiple times." Unclear whether you are asking how to make multiple concurrent calls to accel() or whether your goal is to have a sequence of accel() calls that are concurrent with something else. If it's the former, then you'll need to create a distinct thread object for each thread. If it's the latter, then you could do as Barmar suggested, and create a single thread that calls accel() multiple times, maybe waiting for some "trigger" event between calls.

@Ohm'sLawman so i will have to define a new thread for every call to accel() which will be concurrent and i will have to keep track of which are active? and is there a boolean which tells me if a thread is active?

@XtheGxmerz0 Re, "...and i will have to keep track of which are active?" That's entirely up to you. If some part of your program needs to know which accel(...) calls still are active, then you will have to write the code that keeps track of that. If, on the other hand, the accel() calls each do whatever they need to do, and no other thread needs to know their status, then you can just let them go and do their thing. Python doesn't care whether you keep track of them or not.

This seems like a problem of you trying to start multiple thread multiple times. In Python you can only start 1 thread can be started at once. To resolve this, you'll need to create a new thread object each time you want to execute the accel() function.
import threading

def accel_thread(sect):
    while True:
        if get_sensor():
            accel(sect)

# Create and start a new thread for each section
threads = []
for sect in range(num_sections):  # Assuming num_sections is the total number of sections
    thread = threading.Thread(target=accel_thread, args=(sect,))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

# Wait for all threads to finish
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

Here you make a new thread for each section ensuring the that the accel() function is executed independently. This makes sure to wait for all threads to finish using the join() method. This approach should solve your problem.

well, i would want the main code to operate independently of all the accel() threads. can i do this just by getting rid of the join() part?

oh no. the error message is 17892 characters long... it says NameError: name 'accel' is not defined
